# 'Channel' object has no attribute 'unary_unary' error when calling prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, flask, tensorflow-serving, grpc-python

I am trying to create an inference app for my model (language classification), and I am getting an error `Channel` object has no attribute `unary_unary`. I can't find any information about this problem anywhere, therefore this post. I am quite new to python and tensorflow area, and I'm still learning.
**Error log looks like this (few last lines)**

```
2019-07-30T12:34:12.24+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "app.py", line 189, in do_inference
   2019-07-30T12:34:12.24+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)
   2019-07-30T12:34:12.24+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_serving/apis/prediction_service_pb2_grpc.py", line 40, in __init__
   2019-07-30T12:34:12.24+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     self.Classify = channel.unary_unary(
   2019-07-30T12:34:12.24+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR AttributeError: 'Channel' object has no attribute 'unary_unary'
```

I am using flask for creating web service that consumes the model.

```py
@app.route('/LangDet', methods=['POST'])
def do_inference():
    # get deployed model details
    token = get_access_token()
    model_name = request.path[1:]
    query_string = {"modelName": model_name}
    headers = {
        'Authorization': token
    }
    res = requests.get(deployment_url, headers=headers, params=query_string)
    model_info = json.loads(res.text)
    if int(model_info["count"]) < 1:
        return Response('404 Not Found: Model ' + model_name + ' is unavailable.', status=404)
    else:
        latest_version = [0, 0]
        for index, model in enumerate(model_info["modelServers"]):
            if int(model["specs"]["models"][0]["modelVersion"]) > latest_version[0]:
                latest_version = [int(model["specs"]["models"][0]["modelVersion"]), index]

        model_host = model_info["modelServers"][latest_version[1]]["endpoints"][0]
        credentials = implementations.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates=bytes(model_host["caCrt"], 'ascii'))
        channel = implementations.secure_channel(str(model_host["host"]), int(model_host["port"]), credentials)
        stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)
```

after declaring stub, app throws exception. What seems to be an issue here and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about the packages you have installed? The output of `pip freeze` would be helpful.If you could print out `channel` and `dir(channel)` in `/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_serving/apis/prediction_service_pb2_grpc.py` just before line 49, that would also be immensely helpful.

Comment: I have already solved this issue. Problem was that instead of using grpc to create channel, I was using grpc.beta implementations, which has no such parameter.

Answer (score 2):

While it appears that the original poster figured this out, for anyone else who encounters this, here is the solution.

Instead of:

```
channel = grpc.beta.implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
```

Use:

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel(server)
```

Note that while the beta implementation accepts the host and port separately, the second method accepts them together as a single argument. So for example,

```
insecure_channel(0.0.0.0, 9999)
```

becomes

```
insecure_channel(0.0.0.0:9999)
```